# Высоконагруженный и большой проект на PHP

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord, solid

Я бывал на конференциях, где говорили, что Active Record штука не удобная. Потому что не отвечает принципам SOLID, и когда проект вырастает очень сложно становится какие-то изменения в него вносить. Сам я замечал, что AR делает не самые хорошие, оптимизированные запросы.

В одном проекте онлайн-игры я встречал такой паттерн как Data Mapper, который заполняет соответствующие сущности-классы. И как я понимаю любые процессы необходимо выделять в отдельный класс и никак не привязывать к конкретной сущности (как это делается в моделях AR).

Вот в чём вопрос. Какие есть лучше практики для крупного проекта на PHP? Являются ли Data Mapper лучшим решением? Может быть вообще Active Record не так плох и нужно просто по необходимости дорабатывать запросы? Стоит ли использовать вообще фреймврок?

Comment: Ну здесь не хотелось бы холиварить по поводу php. Есть крупные проекты, которые работают на php. На моём опыте крупная онлайн игра спокойно работала, не задыхаясь на одном сервачке на php. Да и на том же java у вас также возникнет вопрос юзать маппер или AR. Вопрос мало привязан к языку программирования. Мне интересно послушать опытных людей, если они здесь, что они думают о DDD, и стоит ли этим вообще заморачиваться.

Comment: Абстракция + ORM + DDD + сервисная архитектура = счастье

Comment: @korytoff а может есть опен-сорс какой-нибудь с таким стэком? Чтобы посмотреть на хороший тон использования всего этого.

Comment: Фреймворк Symfony + Doctrine, DDD это подход, про него надо много читать и изучать, сервисная архитектура это тоже просто подход

Comment: Ну я понимаю, что подход, просто интересно посмотреть проекты, в которых используется такой подход. Спасибо, попробую почитать про сервисную архитектуру